# A question about 了 and a verb 挂

Tags: grammar

Below is a list of sentences. Some might be a bit strange, but I would like to hear a way to mend them using only 在着了 and other such particles (i.e. no time words and other adverbs).

Is my translation right?

1. 墙上挂一幅画。-"Picture hangs on the wall" as a rule, usuall it does.
2. 墙上在挂一幅画。- "Picture is being hang on the wall", the process of hanging is not yet over.
3. 墙上挂着一幅画。- "Picture is hanging on the wall", as a result of being hanged in (3).
4. 墙上挂了一幅画。- "Picture **IS** hanging", i.e. the picture is indeed as a fact reality is hanging there.
5. 墙上挂着了一幅画。 - ??? i'm stuck here...

Comment: 3✓,5✗:feeding doubtful sections to online dictionaries (example part) may help, e.g. 着了 very doubtful to users, grammar, e.g.＂实用现代汉语语法＂ on aspect particles 动态助词，了、着、过 say 过 and 了 can be combined, but nothing about combining 着 with 了, online can find examples of 着了, zhaole,灯着了(the light is on), 4:挂了 was hung up, (see dictionaries on other meanings of 挂了),1,2 sound unusual

Answer (score 2):

> 1.墙上挂一幅画

Just a neutral description and the meaning is context-dependent

> 2.墙上在挂一幅画

Your translation is correct

> 3.墙上挂着一幅画
>
> 4.墙上挂了一幅画

I don't see any difference.Both means "A picture is hanging on the wall"

> 5.墙上挂着了一幅画

This is gramatically incorrect and doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to say:

画被挂在墙上.
The picture was hung on the wall. (We are not interested in 'by whom')

PS: 2. "The picture is being *hung* on the wall"

Answer (score 0):

To me:

1. 墙上挂一幅画 sounds like a incomplete sentence.
2. 墙上挂着一幅画: The picture is hanging on the wall.
3. 墙上挂了一幅画: The picture was hung on the wall. // indicating completion
4. 墙上在挂一幅画 sounds incorrect, because the subject(a person) should not be omitted in this case. It should be like: 有人正在往墙上挂一幅画.
5. 墙上挂着了一幅画: this sentence is incorrect. It should be either 墙上挂了一幅画 or 墙上挂了一幅画.